# Kotlin: Difference between {} and () while using map transform?

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to kotlin. Ive always used the map transform with curly braces. Then -

Why does this work ->

```
val x = someList.map(::SomeConstructor)
```

and this doesn't?

```
val x = someList.map{ ::SomeConstructor }
```

I didn't find usage of map with circular brackets anywhere on the online tutorials.

Please try to explain in detail, or provide suitable reference article.

Comment: `{ ::SomeConstructor }` is a lambda which ignores its argument and returns `::SomeConstructor`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you ask is explained [in this official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter).

If *and only if* the last argument of a function is a lambda, you can extract it from the call paranthesis, to put it inline on the right of the function. It allows a nicer DSL syntax.

**EDIT**: Let's make an example :

One of the good use-case is context programming. Imagine you've got a closeable object. You want to delimit its usage to ensure it's properly closed once not needed anymore. In Java, you've got the try-with-resources:

```java
try (final AutoCloseable myResource = aquireStuff()) {
  // use your resource here.
}
```

Kotlin provide the `use` function. Now, you can do either :

```
acquireStuff().use( { doStuff1(it) ; doStuff2(it) } )
```

or write :

```
acquireStuff().use {
  doStuff1(it)
  doStuff2(it)
}
```

It looks like a Java try-w-resource, but is extensible to any of your API. Allowing you to design libraries giving advanced constructs to end-users.

Comment: Oh nice. What do you mean by DSL syntax?

Comment: It looks nicer than wrapping everything in parens.

Comment: It might be a subjective argument. But all languages C++, Java, or even for that matter python, have parameters wrapped in parenthesis. Isnt this a horrible looking syntax (no offence :P), because it looks as if it is the function body declaration.

Comment: That's the aim. Considering lambda functions as code blocks executing in a *particular context* given by the function. The syntax make the function name and other parameters a prefix to the code block, creating sort of a context identification.

Comment: God, that's some high level stuff ! I'm sure I'll understand it once I'm more familiar with kotlin. But anyway, thanks for the patience and the replies !

Comment: I never even thought about it that way. To me, it's just easier to read code without all the nested brackets of various kinds, and it's easier to write code for a long lambda and not have to keep track of an extra parenthesis you have to close many lines down. Java and Kotlin don't have pointers. If you've dealt with long nested callback interfaces, you'll love this feature.