# What do these lines of code mean in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, get, netty, spring-webflux

I see creation of GET request based on WebFlux httpClient (Netty under the hood) in Kotlin language. But I don't know what these elements of code mean:

```
return client
    .get()
    .uri{
        it.path(%some_path%)
                .queryParam("%some_param%", value)
                .build()
    }.header(...)
    .awaitExchange()
    .awaitBody()
```

What does 'it' mean?

What do curly braces after 'uri' mean?

Is this syntax Kotlin-specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it is. The curly braces and its content represent a lambda, and `it` is a shortcut: for lambdas with a single parameter, you're not forced to name it yourself. Kotlin provides an implicit naming: 'it'.

So, in your example, what is uri { ... } ? What is this keyword followed by a lambda ? Well, `uri` is simply a member method on Netty client, and it takes a lambda as argument. But, Kotlin allows to write lambda outside function parenthesis. So, instead of writing `uri({ ... })`, you just write `uri() { .. }`. And when there is "no other argument except the lambda" we can omit the parenthesis as well. So we can write `uri { ... }` instead of `uri() { ... }`

For reference:

Kotlin official documentation:

[Lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html):

1. [Passing trailing lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter)
2. [it: implicit name of a single argument](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter)

Another response about lambda as function parameters in Kotlin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60868804/2678097